# Why is context reduction necessary?

Tags: haskell, types, type-inference, typechecking

I've just read [this paper](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse590p/06sp/multi.pdf) ("Type classes: an exploration of the design space" by Peyton Jones & Jones), which explains some challenges with the early typeclass system of Haskell, and how to improve it.

Many of the issues that they raise are related to *context reduction* which is a way to reduce the set of constraints over instance and function declarations by following the "reverse entailment" relationship.

e.g. if you have somewhere `instance (Ord a, Ord b) => Ord (a, b) ...` then within contexts, `Ord (a, b)` gets reduced to `{Ord a, Ord b}` (reduction does not always shrink the number of constrains).

I did not understand from the paper why this reduction was necessary.

Well, I gathered it was used to perform some form of type checking. When you have your reduced set of constraint, you can check that there exist some instance that can satisfy them, otherwise it's an error. I'm not too sure what the added value of that is, since you would notice the problem at the use site, but okay.

But even if you have to do that check, why use the result of reduction inside inferred types? The paper points out it leads to unintuitive inferred types.

The paper is quite ancient (1997) but as far as I can tell, context reduction is still an ongoing concern. The Haskell 2010 spec does mention the inference behaviour I explain above ([link](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch4.html#x10-910004.5.3)).

So, why do it this way?

Answer (score 9):

I don't know if this is The Reason, necessarily, but it might be considered A Reason: in early Haskell, type signatures were only permitted to have "simple" constraints, namely, a type class name applied to a type variable. Thus, for example, all of these were okay:

```
Ord a => a -> a -> Bool
Eq a => a -> a -> Bool
Graph gr => gr n e -> [n]
```

But none of these:

```
Ord (Tree a) => Tree a -> Tree a -> Bool
Eq (a -> b) => (a -> b) -> (a -> b) -> Bool
Graph Gr => Gr n e -> [n]
```

I think there was a feeling then -- and still today, as well -- that allowing the compiler to infer a type which one couldn't write manually would be a bit unfortunate. Context reduction was a way of turning the above signatures either into ones that could be written by hand as well *or* an informative error. For example, since one might reasonably have

```
instance Ord a => Ord (Tree a)
```

in scope, we could turn the illegal signature `Ord (Tree a) => ...` into the legal signature `Ord a => ...`. On the other hand, if we don't have any instance of `Eq` for functions in scope, one would report an error about the type which was inferred to require `Eq (a -> b)` in its context.

This has a couple of other benefits:

1. Intuitively pleasing. Many of the context reduction rules do not change whether the type is legal, but do reflect things humans would do when writing the type. I'm thinking here of the de-duplication and subsumption rules that let you turn, e.g. `(Eq a, Eq a, Ord a)` into just `Ord a` -- a transformation one definitely would want to do for readability.
2. This can frequently catch stupid errors; rather than inferring a type like `Eq (Integer -> Integer) => Bool` which can't be satisfied in a law-abiding way, one can report an error like `Perhaps you did not apply a function to enough arguments?`. Much friendlier!
3. It becomes the compiler's job to pinpoint what went wrong. Instead of inferring a complicated context like `Eq (Tree (Grizwump a, [Flagle (Gr n e) (Gr n' e') c]))` and complaining that the context is not satisfiable, it instead is forced to reduce this to the constituent constraints; it will instead complain that we couldn't determine `Eq (Grizwump a)` from the existing context -- a much more precise and actionable error.

Comment: It would be nice to have a way to block up the third under certain circumstances, particularly where the ultimate unsatisfiable constraint involves non-exported names. Failures using `Data.Constraint.Forall` can lead to error messages that involve (necessarily) non-exported skolem families that end users would be better off not seeing. If you write `Forall p =>` and that doesn't work out, you'll hear back that GHC couldn't satisfy `p (Skolem p)`, which doesn't seem quite so lovely.

Comment: I don't think that's the reason, because the paper does discuss this point abundantly. It in fact suggests to drop this restriction (and as far as I can tell, all the suggestions for improvement made in the conclusion of the paper were adopted in Haskell 98). For instance contexts, it still proposes to keep simple constraints, and the motivation is ... not breaking context reduction. So the causality seems rather in the other direction.

Comment: On another note, I agree to your reduction example (point 1), but that does not need reduction via reverse entailment (just the identity and super-class relationships). For the rest, I think reduction is actually confusing, since it does not match to the set of constraints you defined. And changing the way the instances are provided can change the type of your expression!

Comment: You are incorrect about Haskell '98: the restriction I suggest is correct for both Haskell 98 and Haskell 2010. Only GHC extensions relax this; and indeed from my perusal of the "conclusion" section of the linked paper, basically all of the recommendations became GHC extensions rather than part of the language proper. I'm not sure what part of my answer makes you think that I claim "simple instance contexts" is the cause for context reduction -- I don't mention instance contexts at all. Type signature contexts are the cause; and making these more complicated should not break context reduction.

Comment: You are right about the standard. I did not believe that you meant *instance* contexts were the rationale for reduction, but re-reading myself I agree my point about them makes little sense. Still, the paper wants to uphold context reduction, despite wanting to relax restrictions on type signatures contexts. So the need for context reduction can hardly be motivated by the need for simple type signature contexts, right?

Answer (score 5):

I think this is indeed desirable in a dictionary passing implementation. In such an implementation, a "dictionary", that is, a tuple or record of functions is passed as implicit argument for every type class constraint in the type of the applied function.

Now, the question is simply when and how those dictionaries are created. Observe that for simple types like `Int` by necessity all dictionaries for whatever type class `Int` is an instance of will be a constant. 
Not so in the case of parameterized types like lists, `Maybe` or tuples. It is clear that to show a tuple, for instance, the `Show` instances of the actual tuple elements need to be known. Hence such a polymorphic dictionary cannot be a constant.

It appears that the principle guiding the dictionary passing is such that only dictionaries for types that appear as type variables in the type of the applied function are passed. Or, to put it differently: no redundant information is replicated.

Consider this function:

```
 f :: (Show a, Show b) => (a,b) -> Int
 f ab = length (show ab)
```

The information that a tuple of show-able components is also showable, thus a constraint like `Show (a,b)` needs not to appear when we already know `(Show a, Show b)`.

An alternative implementation would be possible, though, where the caller .would be responsible to create and pass dictionaries. This could work without context reduction, such that the type of `f` would look like:

```
f :: Show (a,b) => (a,b) -> Int
```

But this would mean that the code to create the tuple dictionary would have to be repeated on every call site. And it is easy to come up with examples where the number of necessary constraints actually increases, like in:

```
g :: (Show (a,a), Show(b,b), Show (a,b), Show (b, a)) => a -> b -> Int
g a b = maximum (map length [show (a,a), show (a,b), show (b,a), show(b,b)])
```

It is instructive to implement a type class/instance system with actual records that are explicitly passed. For example:

```
data Show' a = Show' { show' :: a -> String }
showInt :: Show' Int
showInt = Show' { show' = intshow } where
      intshow :: Int -> String
      intshow = show
```

Once you do this you will probably easily recognize the need for "context reduction".

Comment: If "an alternative [dictionary-passing] implementation... could work without context reduction", what motivates the claim that context reduction "is necessary in a dictionary passing implementation"?

Comment: It makes sense, although I'd be disappointed if that turns out to be the answer. Still I'm not convinced, because (1) it's a bit weird that dictionary-passing is not part of the spec, but context reduction is, (2) the paper does mention this benefit of context reduction (section 4.3 points 2 and 4), but as a trade-off that informs how context reduction should be done, rather than as a reason for introducing context reduction in the first place.